# How to get the full StackTrace of WCF service exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I have enabled `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` in *web.config*:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

But throwing an exception in  my service like this:

```
private void Bar()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("blah blah blah");
}
```

Shows a callastack like this:

```
blah blah blah

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.GetData(Int32 value)
   at Service1Client.GetData(Int32 value)
```

I cannot see the exception was within the `Bar()` method.

Even if a use `FaultException`:

```
private void Bar()
{
    throw new FaultException("blah blah blah");
}
```

I still cannot see the exception was at the `Bar()` method:

```
blah blah blah

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.GetData(Int32 value)
   at Service1Client.GetData(Int32 value)
```

The callstack I would like to see is:

```
at WcfService1.Service1.Bar()
at WcfService1.Service1.Foo()
at WcfService1.Service1.GetData(Int32 value)
at SyncInvokeGetData(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Is there any way to get the full StackTrace of the exception?

Comment: I do get full stack trace info just by printing `ex.ToString()` : `System.InvalidOperationException: blah blah blah
   at WcfService5.Service5.Bar() in C:\Users\devl\stackoverflow\WcfService5\Service5.svc.cs:line 22
   at WcfService5.Service5.GetData(Int32 value) in C:\Users\devl\stackoverflow\WcfService5\Service5.svc.cs:line 17`